# get count of all related column on relationship

Tags: sqlite

in sqlite i have this tables:

```
  CREATE TABLE sessions(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    session_name TEXT,
    session_comment TEXT,
    session_type INTEGER,
    date_time TEXT)

  CREATE TABLE barcodes(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    barcode TEXT,
    session_id INTEGER,
    enter INTEGER,
    exit INTEGER,
    date_time TEXT)
```

`sessions` is main table and i store some data in other table as `barcodes` with specifying `session_id` in `barcodes` table, now i want to get all column data from `sessions` with count of all `barcodes` table witch `session_id` in that equals with `sessions.id`

for example:

```
select *, count(barcodes) as cnt from sessions 
left join barcodes on sessions.id = barcodes.session_id
```

Comment: The tags you have been using are not appropriate for this question. Please take the [tour], review [what are tags and how should I use them?](//stackoverflow.com/help/tagging). Remember to at least read the mouseover on the tags you are using when asking a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try below query

```
 SELECT *, COUNT(b.barcodes) as cnt FROM 
   sessions s 
 LEFT JOIN barcodes  b ON s.id = b.session_id
 GROUP BY b.id
```

Comment: this command return multiple row from parent table as `sessions` with same `id`

Comment: please attache screenshot of the output